# copy sqlite .db file between between android tablet and desktop running windows 7

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, synchronization

I want to synchronize between two databases,  one is an android tablet using SQLite and the other is a desktop also with SQLite running windows 7.

either by bluetooth or wifi\TCP-IP. what is the best way to synchronize between the two database tables on two different computers.

example is in the morning get the database table from the desktop and copy it to the database table on the android tablet so all the recent information is visible on the tablet, and later at the end of the day copy the table or any new information collected on the tablet back to the desktop computer.

is there a combination of android libraries and software for the desktop running windows 7 that would make this synchronization easier?

EDIT: i slightly changed the question, just found out that I don't need to deal with MYSQL, will be using SQLite on both the android tablet and the desktop computer.

Comment: what is your data size?is it huge?

Comment: vary small, can be transferred either as the .db file or all the info as JSON string only a 400 characters long

Comment: please have a look at my answer ,it may help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Create Database on remote server(Say WAMP)

2)Make the following connections-
 a)Desktop=>Server
 b)Android=>Server

3)Post your data as a JSON string on server

4)Parse the JSON string and put the records in database on server(You can use PHP)

5)Now you can access this data from server to Desktop as well as in android.

6)As the updated data is on server you don't have to worry about your android and desktop

Answer (score 1):

Using a remote server is much slower, adds an extra point of failure and depends on having a network connection.

Try the Dropbox Sync Api
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync